# Hashtable chaining on collisions. How do I create an array of hashtable pointers to linked list objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, hashtable, chaining

It sounds so simple to do, but I cannot figure out the correct code to implement it.

I currently have a doubly linked list class that works well and has been fully tested.  I do not intend to change anything related to this class.

without listing my entire program, within my Hashtable class header file, I have...

```
#define HASHTABLESIZE 15

class Hashtable {

        public:
                typical public methods listed here
        private:
                Data *hashtable[HASHTABLESIZE];
}
```

and my cpp file...

```
Hashtable::Hashtable() {

        LinkedList list[HASHTABLESIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < HASHTABLESIZE; i++) {
                this->hashtable[i] = list[i];
        }
}
```

This is where i am stuck...

```
this->hashtable[i] = list[i];
```

I want an array of pointers to linked list objects.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Data *hashtable[HASHTABLESIZE];` -- Your hash table should not be an array of the data type, but rather an array of instances of your doubly linked list class (which you say you have already implemented). So it should probably be `LinkedList *hashtable[HASHTABLESIZE];`.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Comment: In addition to @AndreasWenzel's answer, this array (array of linked lists) is usually called `buckets`. But anyway it would be also useful to provide definition of `Data`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel.  Thank you.  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe you can use vector in STL.

```
std::vector<LinkedList> hashtable;
hashtable.reserve(HASHTABLESIZE);
for(int i = 0; i < HASHTABLESIZE; ++i)
        hashtable.push_back(list[i]);
```

Comment: I believe the whole point of what the OP is doing is to program a hash table without the help of the Standard Template Library. If the OP had wanted to create a hash table with the help of the standard template library, he could have simply used [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for this.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: OP could just as reasonably use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` and `std::vector` so he can focus on the hash table aspects, and not be simultaneously debugging mistakes in other code.  Even if planning to do the whole thing eventually, starting with the hash table, then replacing the supporting classes isn't bad practice - in particular, it encourages writing replacements with a similar API.